# Adding repository

Tags: software-sources, opera

The official documentation page to install opera says to add this:

> deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free

Somehow this:

> http://deb.opera.com/opera/

ended up in the url field of the edit source dialog box.  It ended up there from a previous unsuccessful attempt (epic fail - I destroyed updater, software center, and synaptic).  The words stable and non-free are in other fields: stable is in 'distribution', i will change that to raring so that it looks like the official ubuntu documentation page.  non-free is in 'components'.

So what should be in the url field?

I will change distro to raring.

Is non-free ok to be in component?

4theye - i will try - I don't know how:

[image: software center - add / edit source]

hope that woked.

Comment: Can you please post a screen print?

Comment: That should be fine. Now, do `sudo apt-get update` from a terminal.

Comment: That did it. It showed up in software center.