# How to add a GPG key to the apt sources keyring?

Tags: apt, gnupg

[Ubuntu Doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OperaBrowser) page says this:

> It is advisable that you add the Opera GPG key.
>
> `wget -qO - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -`

Where do I add that?

I want to take the advice but I don't know what part of software center to add gpg keys to.

Comment: I believe that is a one line command to enter into terminal

Comment: .msi in Ubuntu is called .deb.

Comment: As a side note, adding keys you fetch over non-HTTPS breaks any security that signing packages added. Wherever possible, you should download keys over a secure channel (https://).

Comment: [Do not use apt-key](https://askubuntu.com/a/1307181/307747)

Answer (score 137, accepted):

> **Note from Moderators:** This solution is no longer functional since apt-key has been deprecated.  However, there is no capability to change if a message is accepted or not, other than deletion of the answer, and for historical reasons AND the massive number of upvotes since the original post in 2013 prevent us from deleting this post.
>
> **Please do not raise flags regarding "insecure" and "deprecated" natures of this answer.**

---

This a a one line command to enter in terminal. See
[What is a terminal and how do I open and use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-a-terminal-and-how-do-i-open-and-use-it)

To use it, you would paste the entire command in the terminal (remember to use https):

```
wget -qO - https://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

But of course, it is daunting just copying and pasting commands without knowing what they are doing, and having no instructions on how to undo their actions, so here is a basic breakdown of the commands:

- `wget` downloads something from a server. See [wget manual for Ubuntu 16.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/wget.1.html).
- `|` is a pipline, which takes the output of one command and runs it into the input of another
- `apt-key add` adds a package key

So it basically downloads the key and then adds it in one command.

I tested the command and it should work.

---

Now to verify that it worked, run this command (from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/107189/47291)):

```
apt-key list
```

This will list the keys added and the key from Opera should be listed on the bottom like this:

```
pub   1024D/30C18A2B 2012-10-29 [expires: 2014-10-29]
uid                  Opera Software Archive Automatic Signing Key 2013 <packager@opera.com>
sub   4096g/C528FCA9 2012-10-29 [expires: 2014-10-29]
```

The linked answer also shows that you can remove the key if needed, using:

```
sudo apt-key del 30C18A2B
```

with `30C18A2B` being the key-id from the list.

---

After performing that command, and setting up the sources exactly like in [your screen-shot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291034/adding-repository), do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install opera
```

(note there are some random warnings, but nothing that affects the install or software center operations)

And for the removal (just in case): [What is the correct way to completely remove an application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application)

---

So in summary:

- Add repository
  [image]
- Add key with `apt-key`
- Install in terminal with `apt-get`
- Search in dash
  [image]

Comment: "apt-key adv" allows one to download the key from a public keyserver.

Comment: After adding the key with `apt-key add`,  the .key file (in this case, "archive.key") can be deleted without consequence, right? The key (the information, not the file) has already been added to a list somewhere, so the file should no longer be needed.

Comment: @Cerran, correct. APT keeps keys _somewhere else_ (`/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` and `/var/lib/apt/keyrings/` for example.)

Comment: If you get an SSL error with wget, you can use curl instead: `curl -L  https://deb.opera.com/archive.key  | sudo apt-key add -`

Comment: Isn't apt-key deprecated? I keep seeing this warning everywhere. Here, for example (installation guide for Nvidia Cuda): https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.7.1/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ubuntu-installation-network

Answer (score 62):

**If you are manually adding a key from a PPA, use:**

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 00000000
```

**Alternatively, if you do not want to use apt-key:**

```
sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/change-ppa-name-here.gpg --recv-keys 00000000
```

Replace the `00000000` with the second part of the key informed in the PPA website that you want to add.

For example, if you find this line:

```
 4096R/7BF576066
```

Use only the second part (no matter its size), which in this example is `7BF576066`

Comment: are errors like `gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available` and `gpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection refused` common?

Comment: No, errors like these aren't common. Maybe you're writing the wrong key.

Comment: equivalent without apt-key: `sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/my-ppa.gpg --recv-keys 00000000`

Comment: FYI eddygeeks comment works. This should be a full answer. BUT I had already populated my-ppa.gpg with incorrect instructions from elsewhere on the Intertubes. I first had to remove the old-style my-ppa.gpg. I got errors when following this procedure without removing the file.

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaClayton , I updated the answer

Answer (score 38):

Newer versions of apt also support the following:

```
apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://deb.opera.com/archive.key
```

This method also provides more detailed feedback as well, e.g.:

```
gpg: key 7BD9BF62: public key "signing key <username@domain.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
```

This also has the added bonus of removing the need for additional dependencies like wget or curl.

Comment: apt-key adv does not seem to work for https

Comment: @dani-h You need `gnupg-curl` to use HTTPS if you are using GPG 1.x.

Comment: `apt-key adv --fetch-keys` will only fetch **one** key from the URL, and if the URL contains multiple keys, please use `wget | apt-key add` instead.

Comment: It seems to work with https already (just tested on Ubuntu 17.10)

Answer (score 7):

apt-key now seems to be deprecated, I have created a script that will detect and get the missing keys, you can get it [here](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2320252).

```
#!/bin/sh -e
tmp="$(mktemp)"
sudo apt-get update 2>&1 | sed -En 's/.*NO_PUBKEY ([[:xdigit:]]+).*/\1/p' | sort -u > "${tmp}"
cat "${tmp}" | xargs sudo gpg --keyserver "hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com:443" --recv-keys  # to /usr/share/keyrings/*
cat "${tmp}" | xargs -L 1 sh -c 'sudo gpg --yes --output "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/$1.gpg" --export "$1"' sh  # to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/*
rm "${tmp}"
```

Answer (score 6):

You should not add third-party keys via `apt-key add`. These keys can then be used to sign any package on your machine, including those from the archive. Now you should only allow the key to sign only a specific package. [Complete answer on UNIX.SE from user Trudy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/582853).

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you want to [add `docker`'s repo key](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) (an ASCII-armored key):

```
$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg \
    | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
```

If you're not sure if the key is ASCII-armored:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | file -
/dev/stdin: PGP public key block Public-Key (old)
```

For a non-armored key the output will be along the lines of:

```
/dev/stdin: OpenPGP Public Key Version 4, Created ..., RSA (Encrypt or Sign, 4096 bits); User ID; Signature; OpenPGP Certificate
```

And to add it you need:

```
$ sudo curl -fsSL https://... -o /etc/apt/keyrings/NAME.gpg
```

More on it can be found [here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/01/apt-key-is-deprecated-how-to-add.html). But it suggests to install keys to `/usr/share/keyrings`, which is the location for package maintainers. More on it below.

For [`apt` < 2.4.0](https://git.launchpad.net/apt/tree/debian/changelog?h=2.4.0) you need to create `/etc/apt/keyrings` before adding the key ([Debian link](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/2.4.0/debian/changelog)):

> apt (2.4.0) unstable; urgency=medium
> ...
>
> - Install an empty /etc/apt/keyrings directory. This directory is intended to provide an alternative to /usr/share/keyrings for placing keys used with signed-by.

That means before [Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/apt), [Debian 12 Bookworm](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/apt).

Deprecating `apt-key` is a security measure. You can learn more on it [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1307181/186999). As such, adding files to `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` is also insecure. Because `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` is a way to add keys to the keyring (`/etc/apt/trusted.gpg`) w/o `apt-key add`, by copying files.

Also note [that](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/sources.list.5.html):

> The recommended locations for keyrings are /usr/share/keyrings for keyrings managed by packages, and /etc/apt/keyrings for keyrings managed by the system operator.

---

`apt-key` is deprecated since [`2.1.8`](https://git.launchpad.net/apt/tree/debian/changelog?h=2.1.8) ([Debian link](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/2.1.8/debian/changelog)):

> apt (2.1.8) unstable; urgency=medium
> ...
>
> - Fully deprecate apt-key, schedule removal for Q2/2022

In terms of releases that would be [Ubuntu 21.10 Impish](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/apt), [Debian 11 Bullseye](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/apt). The [commit](https://git.launchpad.net/apt/commit?id=ee284d5917d09649b68ff1632d44e892f290c52f) ([Debian link](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/commit/ee284d5917d09649b68ff1632d44e892f290c52f)).

Ability to specify `signed-by` in `apt` sources was added in [`1.1.exp9`](https://git.launchpad.net/apt/tree/debian/changelog?h=1.1.exp9) ([Debian link](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/1.1.exp9/debian/changelog)):

> apt (1.1~exp9) experimental; urgency=medium
> ...
>
> - implement Signed-By option for sources.list

The [commit](https://git.launchpad.net/apt/commit?id=b0d408547734100bf86781615f546487ecf390d9) ([Debian link](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/commit/b0d408547734100bf86781615f546487ecf390d9)).

Answer (score 1):

Another way where you just have an .asc key, you download the .asc key and add it to the keyring.

For instance -

```
curl -L https://packages.riot.im/debian/repo-key.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to "dearmor" (aka convert to binary) before storing your pgp key in `trusted.gpg.d`:

```
cat mykey.gpg | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mykey.gpg
```