# How do you install opera on Ubuntu (13.04 32 bit)?

Tags: software-installation, opera

I'm struggling to install, if someone would give me a tutorial, then I would be grateful. I'm guessing this is the same for all Ubuntu versions.

Comment: 13.04 is end of life. Please upgrade to a supported release.

Comment: @Rinzwind e.g. 12.04 or 14.04. However, these instructions are the same for any version.

Comment: @Tim I know; I did not close vote cuz I agree is does not matter what OS it is.

Comment: this might help: http://askubuntu.com/a/291095/47291

Comment: also if your are trying to install the new one - http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/06/opera-linux-chromium-download-released it is only on 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This applies to any Ubuntu version.

It is quite self explanatory - go to opera.com and click download -  a tutorial really isn't required here. Nevertheless...

Visit the [opera download page](http://www.opera.com/computer/linux), then select `Ubuntu` and `Debian package`. Click download. Then open the `.deb` file and click install.