# sudo: unable to resolve host architect

Tags: apt, database, mongodb

I am trying to install mongodb on my laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. When I executed this command

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
```

this error showed up:

```
 sudo: unable to resolve host architect
```

Note: I have tried with `[ arch=i686,i686 ]` which is my pc architecture. What's the problem?

Comment: does the error says architect or architecture? is it translated?

Comment: This does **not** appear to be a duplicate.  This is about *host architecture*, while the other question involves *hostname*.  Also, the solution to the other question will definitely not work here.

Comment: @earthmeLon Sudo doesn't handle anything regarding host architecture, but it does handle hostname lookups.

Comment: @Zanna AFAIK, `sudo` doesn't handle architecture management, so it should be impossible for `sudo` to error out on architecture, either. Further, one doesn't really resolve architectures. :P

Comment: @KazWolfe yeah I thought this post couldn't be about architecture really

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you got that command, but the following command would have worked:

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
```

Now that you already have `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list`, you need to edit it (ie: with `vim` or `nano`) so that contains a *single line* that reads:

```
deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse
```

Be sure to run `apt-get update` to sync and update available packages, and [add 10gen's apt key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291035/how-to-add-a-gpg-key-to-the-apt-sources-keyring).