# Problem installing phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine)

Tags: apt, repository, phpmyadmin, 19.10

I just recently upgraded from Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo) to Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine). My phpMyAdmin was removed while upgrading. Now I can't install it again.

I tried using:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-gettext
```

but it shows something like this:

```
Package phpmyadmin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'phpmyadmin' has no installation candidate
```

So I searched from phpMyAdmin, `apt search phpmyadmin`, but I didn't find any.

How can I install phpMyAdmin on this version?

Comment: Check that you have the `universe` repository installed.

Comment: Its also no more in the packages repo: https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/phpmyadmin - disco is last one listed there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am a member of the packaging team and we are doing our best to get back phpMyAdmin in the Debian buster repository ASAP (buster-backports), this will update Ubuntu afterwards.

You can use our PPA: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phpmyadmin/+bug/1837775/comments/7

There is an open issue on our tracker for Ubuntu: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15515

And for Debian:
https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15236

Hope the PPA or installing manually using our website will help someone

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looking forward to having this in the main repo soon......

Comment: Correction - this won't make it into Ubuntu 19.10 because the package was already removed, and it might need some very heavy Release Team interaction to actually *get* included in Ubuntu again, and chances are it won't be put into 19.10 except via PPA because the archive is more or less 'frozen' there, to my knowledge.

Comment: Nothing happens if I try to add the ppa with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa`

Comment: Did you install add-apt-repository ?

Comment: @WilliamDesportes, yes it is installed.

Comment: Please have a look to https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16065#issuecomment-609035410

Maybe adding the repository manually will work, then you can apt-get update and apt-get install phpmyadmin

Comment: I added `deb ppa.launchpad.net/phpmyadmin/ppa/ubuntu eoan main` into **/etc/apt/sources.list** but now I get **Misshaped entry 51 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (URI parse)** if I execute `apt-get install phpmyadmin`

Comment: Edit: I had to add `http://`, I missed it because you did not mentioned it in the other comment. However it does still say that it was unable to found the packet.

Comment: I assume you did run `apt-get update` ?

Comment: Oh forgot it, did just now. But I get an error. It says there is no public key and so it can't verify the signature and thus it refuses to update.

Comment: Oh much better
You an add it with https://askubuntu.com/a/291095/432270 and `apt-get update` once more

Comment: I had to add it like this: `deb [trusted=yes] http://ppa.launchpad.net/phpmyadmin/ppa/ubuntu eoan main` Now it works :) Thanks

Answer (score 14):

To add the ppa mentioned by William Desportes and install phpmyadmin do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Comment: seamless answer.  I suppose ppa: states what ppa to add, and since there is no full path like in a URL but is a local URL continuation with a / it means from the trusted repositories instead of some random URL therefore this looks mostly...mostly...safe?  Right?  I am new to securityand only know basic password auth models.

Comment: Does not work. If I execute `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa` then nothing happens.

Answer (score 5):

Obviously it has been removed for security reasons.

It popped up first in Debian Community: [#916310 - 4.6 should not be shipped in a stable release - Debian Bug report logs](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=916310)

Then in [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phpmyadmin/+bug/1837775)

Ubuntu Forums thread here: [phpmyadmin missing from repository](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2428229)

It seems like some Debians joined the phpMyAdmin project to fix the problem in future releases.

Comment: can I install it by using disco repositories? If so how?

Comment: You know you can install it directly by downloading, uploading und running install?
https://www.phpmyadmin.net/

You can try using disco package, but it might be linked to older php packages that do not exist on eoan, it might be possible to run them with php-fpm, but I think its easier for now to use the manual install.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu "focal" 20.04 has now phpMyAdmin 4.9.2

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/phpmyadmin

Track progress for 19.10 (if some can be done) in https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15515

Comment: How to upgrade from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04 ? I tried `do-release-upgrade -c` but it says `No new release found.`

Comment: No need to upgrade
As I mentioned here: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16065#issuecomment-609035410
You can use "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/phpmyadmin/ppa/ubuntu eoan main"

Comment: Ok thanks. I figured out that 20.04 is getting released tomorrow, thats prob why it was not able to find a new release.

Comment: I added `deb ppa.launchpad.net/phpmyadmin/ppa/ubuntu eoan main` into **/etc/apt/sources.list** but now I get **Misshaped entry 51 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (URI parse)** if I execute `apt-get install phpmyadmin`

Comment: Edit: I had to add `http://`,  However it does still say that it was unable to found the packet.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use [heidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) instead of phpmyadmin.