# When is there going to be a PhpMyAdmin version available for Ubuntu 19.10 without PPA installation?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm just wondering, when is PhpMyAdmin going to be ready for Ubuntu 19.10? Should we wait until the next Ubuntu version?

I know there's a related topic about this ([Problem installing phpmyadmin on ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184416/problem-installing-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-19-10)) but as nothing I've tried seems to solve my problem, I'm thinking of downgrading to 19.04 again.

**P.S.:** This question is different because I wanted to know if there was going to be a date for an official release of PhpMyAdmin for this version of Linux, but looks like it will take some time before this gets done.

I found two excellent alternatives for PhpMyAdmin:

- [Valentina Studio](https://www.valentina-db.com/en/)
- [Dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/)

So, this topic can be closed.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't see it when you run `apt-cache search phpmyadmin`?

Comment: @AlexisWilke No, man. Only appears PhpLiteAdmin, PhpLiteAdmin extensions and Adminer.

Comment: Well... I installed a VPS and I don't see it either... I also tried `snap find php` just in case and it's not a snap either.

Comment: Ah. Your question looks like a duplicate of
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184416/problem-installing-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-19-10

Comment: (duplicate vote too) - Op, you can install it via this official PPA https://launchpad.net/~phpmyadmin/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=eoan

Comment: Looks like definetly there's no way to install PhpMyAdmin in a normal way for this version of linux, only via PPA, it's true that isn't trustable, but in this case, it comes from the "PhpMyAdmin Team", but even like this, there's no guarantee it's going to work, I'll try to look for alternatives and update my post if I find a solution. Thanks guys.

Comment: One alternative is `adminer` and it can be installed with `apt-get`. I don't use those (I use the command line directly) so I'm not sure whether it would be enough in term of functionality.