# How can I install phpmyadmin on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: apt, phpmyadmin

How can I install phpmyadmin on Ubuntu 19.10?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to help without knowing what you already tried, but I see you tagged `apt` so I'm gonna start there.

First of all, you need to update `apt` metadata by running

```
sudo apt update
```

After that you can try

```
apt search 'phpmyadmin*'
```

Notice the `*` wildcard. Also I wrapped the search term with `''` single quotes so Bash will not expand `*` (if it happens to match anything) before APT sees it.

If this doesn't help, then the package is not available in your repository right now. In that case you have these options:

1. Wait - find some info about why it is missing and when it will be back. This is out of scope of this answer, for more info see the [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184416/problem-installing-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-19-10).
2. Install the package from a [PPA](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install phpmyadmin
   ```
3. Try an alternative. I personally prefer [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/en/) which should also be available through `apt`.