# how to solve this phpmyadmin error in ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: 19.10

```
ERROR: Conf phpmyadmin does not exist!
dpkg: error processing package phpmyadmin (--remove):
 installed phpmyadmin package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit
 status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 phpmyadmin
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy phpmyadmin` to the question.

Comment: The line `ERROR: Conf phpmyadmin does not exist!` means 'there is no such file as /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf'. This could have some reasons. Manual deleted, issue during install (out of space), not enough rights on install, ... - But I think there are more errors before. If not, I would try `sudo touch /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf` on the console/terminal.

Answer (score 0):

[Problem installing phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184416/problem-installing-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine/1184865#1184865)

You can use our PPA to fix this issue (if you wanted to re-install), phpMyAdmin is back in Ubuntu 20

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```