# Do I have to add the public key for the repository for installing R?

Tags: apt, r

I follow https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html to install R

```
$ echo "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
$ sudo apt-get update
...
Err:14 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51716619E084DAB9
Reading package lists... Done 
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/adrozdoff/emacs/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: GPG error: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51716619E084DAB9
E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
...
$ sudo apt-get install r-base
```

Does the error message from `apt-get update` mean that I have to add the public key for the repository?

What are some consequences if I leave it?

Why can I still run `apt-get install r-base`?

Why does the following fail?

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 51716619E084DAB9
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.Z9eYn6e4zV/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 51716619E084DAB9
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using some firewall?

Comment: Not sure. It works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repository mentioned in [UBUNTU PACKAGES FOR R](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) includes latest version which is 3.6. However, for 18.04, Ubuntu's Universe repository [still have v3.4](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=r-base&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all). Even if you don't add R's official repository you can still install r-base but obviously that would be v3.4.

> Does the error message from `apt-get update` mean that I have to add the public key for the repository?

Yes if you want to continue using that repository. APT is a very secure package management tool. It uses that public key to authenticate downloaded packages. For full documentation, read [SecureAPT - Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt).

> What are some consequences if I leave it?

APT will keep on complaining and you won't be able to download packages from R's official repositories.

> Why can I still run `apt-get install r-base`?

Because r-base is available in Ubuntu's Universe repository too. You can run `apt-cache policy r-base` to check which version you'll get from which repository.

> Why does the following fail?
>
> ```
> $ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 51716619E084DAB9
> Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.Z9eYn6e4zV/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 51716619E084DAB9
> gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
> ```

Seems like a temporary server side issue. I tried adding the key using the same command and it succeeded.

Comment: Thanks.  Is https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html or other official installation webpage supposed to provide public key?

Comment: @Tim Yeah and it does. Scroll down the README.html and read the SecureAPT section.

Comment: Thanks. It says `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9`, but I ran `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 51716619E084DAB9` with the key reported in the error by `apt update`. Why are the two keys different?

Comment: @Tim They'll both add same key. The actual key is long and may be hard to remember. Key id is comparatively shorter and easier to remember. Key id is the last "X" characters of the actual key. Key id can be of length 8 or 16.

Comment: What are the extra 8-bit prefix in 16 bit used for?

Comment: @Tim Sorry I didn't get you. 51716619E084DAB9 and E084DAB9 both would add same key.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this](https://blog.pcollaog.cl/2009/04/26/agregar-llaves-de-repositorios-apt-en-ubuntu/) looking on gogle(in spanish):

As i see in the log of the console, you have to add some keys(not only the R related, maybe the other ones are about dependencies of the program)

The page say about a key manager, something to easy a bit the problem of add keys:

You should do this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install add-apt-key
```

Then:

```
$ sudo su -
# add-apt-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 51716619E084DAB9
```

I also found another way [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291035/how-to-add-a-gpg-key-to-the-apt-sources-keyring)(English, askubuntu forum; see the acepted answer)

I hope that this work for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Signing your repository is just another way of making it secure and authenticating packages.
Official repositories will always have a gpg key.
If you own a repository, it is your choice if you would like to maintain a certificate and signing methods in your organisation.

By default apt will always look for a gpg, and without one it will ignore the repository's content.
You can skip the gpg check by adding the `--allow-unauthenticated` option to apt-get.
This requires a sudo operation.

example: `sudo apt-get --allow-unauthenticated upgrade`, `sudo apt-get -y --allow-unauthenticated install foo`.

You may also make this option permanent by using your own config file at `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` directory.

In your conf file simply add `APT::Get::AllowUnauthenticated "true";` stanza.

Answer (score 2):

I could solve this problem (on January 2021) by the following instructions provided [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-r-on-debian-10/) and [in the r-project](https://www.r-project.org/) site. The summary was

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 'E19F5F87128899B192B1A2C2AD5F960A256A04AF'
```

But it failed: "gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure" 
According to the info. at the r-project site it can be due to "a firewall blocking port 11371". In that case what can be done is:

1. Search for `0xE19F5F87128899B192B1A2C2AD5F960A256A04AF` at https://keyserver.ubuntu.com.
2. Copy the key block shown when klicking on the link in the line starting with **pub** (The key starts with -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK----- ) into a plain text file which name ends with *.asc (for instance: file_with_key.asc)
3. In the directory where the *.asc file is stored run:

```
$ sudo apt-key add file_with_key.asc
```

4 **[Edit]**. Add the reppositroy. Here it is a bit tricky. The command's formula is:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository 'A_url'
```

Where I have found different options like 
`deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran35/`
`deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/`
`deb http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran40/`
etc. Depending on the system and version you want.
5. Install R

```
$ sudo apt-get update # Here you should see the cloud.r-project 
$ apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

6. Check the R version

```
$ R --version
```